# Possible VARCHAR hash indexing structure in MySql

Tags: mysql, hash, indexing, varchar

**MySql table:**  `id (bigint)` `status (tinyint)` and `string (varchar[250])`

**Content**: Around *36 million* entries, where each string has a **variable** length of *[1 to 250]* chars.

**Desired query**: `SELECT id FROM tb WHERE status=N AND string IN ('str1','str2'...)`

**The problem**: I *NEED* the `string` field to be an `INDEX`

**The IDEA**: Create a separate table called `hash_strings` like this:

```
+--------------------+
| id [bigint]        |
+--------------------+
| str_hash [varchar] | ==> INDEX
+--------------------+
```

...so I  first get the string `ids` using the `hash_strings` table and then I work with a list of `ids` instead of `strings` in the first query. I made a separate table because storing strings and hashes in the same one will make the table be bigger, and the queries run slower.

**Questions**:

- What do you think about it?
- Which hash function should I use? *(32 chars, 16 chars)*

Comment: as I found you use absolutely string match "string IN ('str1')" so it's enough just to add index for field `string`.

Comment: @IgorVizma Thanks Igor. Till now I have always been told that creating an INDEX an a VARCHAR[250] with 36 million entries is too crazy if I want to make many queries (like the one in the example). It's that why I have been searching for weeks what alternative could be the best one. So, why do you think it will be enough? _I thank you your answer, just asking to convince myself ;)_

Comment: sorry, previous one message sent accidentally.
So regarding to the issue - if you do want you want then you must take care for hash_table yourself but if add indexes as I suggest this job does MySQL itself. If you want speed up the query - make sharding by "string" field (hope the field doesn't get changes frequently)

Comment: that's not crazy, that's MySQL routine job but only if you aren't going to make fulltext search or search LIKE "%someword" when indexes won't help then you need implement search engine like SPHINX, Lucene etc.

Comment: @IgorVizma Thank you for the complete answer. Just for curiosity, why does the `full match` search work _(better?)_ than `partial match`... the first has to check the full string, and not so the second one.

Comment: when there uses magic "%" or "_" at the beginning of string index doesn't work (B-tree behaviour) as well as matches more than 30% MySQL uses fullscan instead of indexes so following search will work pretty good: "some string I'm look%" but not "% string I'm look" or "some%". The last one depends on count of rows which started on "some" word. If there all string started from "some" word then index will be failed.